# Running two functions simultaneously on Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing, pygame

I've searched far and wide on the internet and can't find a suitable situation for running my two functions at once. Basically, one function contains the code for using arrow keys to move a smiley face around, and the other one makes a red circle fall from the top of the screen. Here is my code in `main.py`:

```
    import game, prepare
    from multiprocessing import Process
    prepare.setuppygame()
    prepare.setupSM()
    prepare.setupRC()

    #display score for the first time
    prepare.disscore()

    #set starting positions for first time
    game.setStartingPositions()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
      p1 = Process(target=game.go)
      p1.start()
      p2 = Process(target=game.RCfall)
      p2.start()
      p1.join()
      p2.join()
```

I'm not getting one screen with a falling circle and the ability to move around a smiley; I get one screen with a smiley that you can move around and another pygame screen that has a falling circle, but not together. Why isn't multiprocessing working? I'm also open to using threads, if they would work.

Infrastructure: Geany, Python2.7, Windows 7 but programming for Raspberry Pi

Comment: You don't need multiprocessing or even multithreading to do this. It's very easy to do this with a single process and a single thread.

Comment: Agreed with ShashankGupta; you'll want a main loop and a `tick` function that updates all of the elements every frame. That'll be both easier and faster than processes or threads.

Comment: How do you do that? I'm kind of new to python and don't understand it. I didn't used sprites either. Surely if you are updating every frame then there will still be a delay because they are not being run at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe going through this tutorial on the pygame website

http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/chimp/ChimpLineByLine.html

will give you an idea on how to simply accomplish what you want.  It shows how to make an image move by itself on the screen while you move a control image with the cursor.  Not precisely what you want but pretty damn close.